# WorkLight SQL Adapter : Upload an image using SQL Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I need to upload an image to database as blob type using SQL Adapter And also i need to know how to get blob data from SQL Adapter.Will you please help me for inserting and retrieving blob data through SQL Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [an old forum post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014881179):

> Here is what I think of.
>
> 1. Write a servlet or whatever equivalent in your app server. In the servlet, you fetch the image from DB.
> 2. Encode the image binary contents according to BASE64.
> 3. Return the base64 string of the image.
> 4. Write an HTTP Adapter to visit the servlet you just write.
> 5. In your client application, you can insert the image into a  by setting the "src" attribute to some value like
>      "data:charset=some_charset, ". For example,
>      "data:image/gif;base64,".

Message by [MingZheHuang](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/profiles/html/profileView.do?userid=270004WA4U).